# Watch SCSS with a Spring-boot application

Tags: maven, sass, spring-boot

I have a Spring-boot application, in which I'd like to use [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/) to improve my `CSS`. I have successfully configured my `pom` for my `SCSS`file to be compiled into a valid `CSS` during maven compilation. I now would like to have a hot deploy of the `SCSS`. Any time the `SCSS` is changed, I'd like it to be recompiled and redeployed in my launched `spring-boot` app, so that I just have to refresh my browser to see the changes.

My goal is just having to execute the `maven` command:

```
mvn install spring-boot:run sass:watch
```

for it to work. Is it possible?

I have not yet managed to make the `sass:watch` work when run from another terminal, but I assume this is just a pom configuration issue.

EDIT: My application is built as a fat (or uber) jar

Answer (score 3):

Because I had the same issue:

You cannot run spring-boot:run sass:watch as a single command.
Maven is not (really) multi-threaded and the tasks are executed as a sequence. Since both tasks are blocking, the second one will never be executed.

So you need to run two commands from two consoles

```
mvn spring-boot:run 
mvn sass:watch
```

the mvn install is not really needed. If you still want it, put it in the first command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [exec-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html) to execute the `sass:watch` maven goal asynchronously:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <executable>mvn</executable>
        <async>true</async>
        <arguments>
            <argument>sass:watch</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

To execute:

`mvn exec:exec spring-boot:run`

Or you can bind the exec goal to a particular phase (e.g. validate) and/or wrap this in a profile so it only executes when you want it:

`mvn spring-boot:run -P sass`

```xml
<profile>
    <id>sass</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>mvn</executable>
                    <async>true</async>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>sass:watch</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```